# Meaning of 「さすがに」in a particular context

Tags: meaning, words, phrases, context

I think 「さすがに」 generally means something like "Generally acknowledging a fact, but still has more to say regarding that fact in this specific situation". But I recently encountered a usage of this phrase, to which I don't quite think the above explanation is applicable.

To provide the context first, there was a male and a girl making a conversation. The male stood on a stone which was much higher than the place where the girl stood. So in the middle of their conversation, the girl said the following to the male:

> 「いつまで上から見下ろしているつもり？」.

Then the reaction of the male following this remark is:

> 「たしかに」

> 下から覗くよりましだろ、という下品で意味のない冗談はさすがに口にはせず、静馬はそそくさと地上へと降りた。

I think I get the rough meaning of these paragraphs, that is the male (whose name is 「静馬」) accepted the girl's protest and climbed down from the stone so that the two were on the same footing. But at the same time the male came up with a retort, which he decided was rather indecent. At last he refrained from spitting it out. But I don't really understand how「さすがに」 could fit into this paragraph…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple way to understand the さすがに would be that it is a synonym for やはり. For the particular example, not to say the joke is expected from the situation.

More specifically, the following definitions would be relevant.

- 予想・期待したことを、事実として納得するさま。また、その事実に改めて感心するさま。なるほど、やはり。「一人暮らしは―に寂しい」「―（は）ベテランだ」 ([デジタル大辞泉](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E6%B5%81%E7%9F%B3/#jn-88035))
- しかるべき原因が当然の帰結を生んだこと、本性が発揮されたこと、実力や評判に背かないことについて、改めて感嘆するさま。 ([日本国語大辞典](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%95%E3%81%99%E3%81%8C))

In the case of the example, しかるべき原因(the situation) caused 当然の帰結(not to say the joke). (Note there is no element of exclamation).

Basically this さすがに means that doing things otherwise (saying a joke, in the example) is inappropriate in the situation.

---

Example: An employee is going to quit his job. He has a meeting with his supervisor and is told that he will be promoted. Then the employee would think もうすぐ辞めますとはさすがに言えない. (Well, of course he would have to eventually...).